# jquery carousel evolution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change an animation in jquery evolution carousel:

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-carousel-evolution/full_screen_preview/490018

As I have a lot of elements showing up in the slider I would like when clicking on the last one in the back to animate itself to the center without having all the other elements before it stepping and stopping through the center.

I am not good at jquery but I think it has something to do with these lines here:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
            animateImage(i);                                                    
        }              
    };        

    var animateImage = function(i){
        var o = settings,
            item = slideItems.eq(i),
            pos = slidePos(i);

        item.show();
        item.animate(setSlidePosition(pos), o.speed, 'linear', function(){
            hideItem($(this));            
            if (i == numberSlides - 1){
                isAnimationRunning = false ;
                if (currentSlide != targetSlide){ 
                    animateSlide();
                }
                else {
                    self.current = currentSlide ;
                    showVideoOverlay(currentSlide);
                    o.after(self);                  
                }                                                                               
            }
        });
```

any help would be nice